# Turning on verbose logging

Tags: 8, debugging

Is the "Verbose logging" in Drupal actually the PHP errors that can be activated in various ways (.htaccess, php.ini, settings.php) to be seen on screen?

Is it `drush ws --full` ?

From the material I've seen I can't say for sure if there is a unique definition for this concept in Drupal.

I would thank an experienced Drupal programmer to give the final word on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Navigate to admin/config/development/logging and set "All messages, with backtrace information".

Comment: This answer may be actually what you are asking: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/127182/how-to-enable-developer-debug-mode-in-drupal-8?rq=1

Comment: Actually, these are equivalent.