# Is there a standard environmental indicator for Drupal 8 projects?

Tags: 8

I am developing a Drupal 8 site, and I ran into the need to display all errors.
I added this line to my settings file, according to [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/127183/1441):

```
$config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'verbose';
```

But, when I'm ready to make my site live on production, I don't want error details being shown to end-users.

I want to conditionally display errors based on which environment the codebase is sitting on-- local, dev, staging, and production. In Drupal 8, is there a way to indicate which environment the site is running on? A variable or something? Or is this something that I manage myself?

Answer (score 2):

A standard way to use different settings files per environment is through the use of sites folders.  Check out /sites/example.sites.php in your Drupal 8 codebase. It gives instructions.

Basically, you'll copy this file from example.sites.php to sites.php.  You don't need to edit it, (but you can if you want to do something unusual).

Then for each site (or environment), you'll have a separate settings.php file in a folder named after the site.

So you might have

- /sites/example.com/settings.php
- /sites/qa.example.com/settings.php
- /sites/dev.example.com/settings.php
- /sites/example.local/settings.php

If you are using git, you might want to uncomment this 
/sites/example.local/settings.php

```
if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/settings.local.php')) {
  include_once __DIR__ . '/settings.local.php';
}
```

and git exclude

/sites/example.local/settings.local.php

so that each developer can customize his settings.

If you run drush, you can run from the site specific folder on that environment or specify the --uri parameter.

Of course, you could just add conditional code in your /sites/default/settings.php

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'example.com') {
  $config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'hide';
}
```

If you jut want to change one variable, and you know that on your production environment $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] is available and correct, then this is an option.

Comment: Are each `settings.local.php` on different servers managed "manually", instead of in version control, then?

Comment: You could commit it, but on projects I have worked on, we usually don't commit settings.local.php.  If you're going to commit it, there's not much of a  point of including settings.local.php, you could just update the settings.php in that folder.  If you have database credentials, you might not want to put that in your version control.  Of course, depending on your set up, it might be fine to include the database credentials in version control.  In which case, you could just put them in settings.php

Comment: I was hoping for something that "just worked" without any finagling after we deployed the code. I understand the value of the developer customizing their environment, but certain things I just want to have out of the box.

Comment: Then put all of your settings in the settings.php in each site folder, and don't use a settings.local.php

Comment: Would it be fair to characterize your answer as "it is something you manage yourself"?

Comment: Yes, if you want something like codeigniter, you could set an environment variable it in your apache settings and use conditional code.

Comment: _I was hoping for something that "just worked" without any finagling after we deployed the code._ That's something that should be explicitly set up by the developer, the framework shouldn't try to impose that logic. Take Laravel for example, you specify the server's current environment in an .env file that is excluded from version control. Drupal just doesn't have the convention of including that var somewhere; it could if it wanted to, but IMO it's better left up to the dev decide whether they want to solve it in code, through web server environment vars, or whatever else

Answer (score 1):

I want to make this plain and simple for people visiting this question: Based on oknate's answer, **there is no standard environmental indicator in Drupal 8**:

> That's something that should be explicitly set up by the developer,
>   the framework shouldn't try to impose that logic. Take Laravel for
>   example, you specify the server's current environment in an .env file
>   that is excluded from version control. Drupal just doesn't have the
>   convention of including that var somewhere; it could if it wanted to,
>   but IMO it's better left up to the dev decide whether they want to
>   solve it in code, through web server environment vars, or whatever
>   else

If you're a developer coming into an existing Drupal 8 project, you have to be told or figure out how the builders managed environmental awareness, if they did at all.