# Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "<whatever>" plugin does not exist

Tags: updating, plugins

After updading a Drupal site from 8.6.16 to 8.7.1 (PostgreSQL 9.6.13 , Nginx) I get this error in almost every operation (creating a view , installing a module, creating a content type, creating a menu, importing feeds, ....) with diferent plugins ("views.view.*","core.extension","node.type.*","system.menu.*" )

```
Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "{whatever}" plugin does not exist.
Valid plugin IDs for Drupal\Core\TypedData\TypedDataManager are: filter_format, any, float, string, boolean, timespan,[...]
in Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->doGetDefinition() (line 53 de /"path-to-drupal"/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php).
```

but there is **no error** when I create/delete a content (article), user, menu item, ...

I use the drupal-project composer template so my update process was:

```
composer update --with-dependencies webflo/drupal-core-require-dev drupal/* "symfony/*" -d /<path/to/site> --no-interaction ;
cd /path/to/site>
drush updb
drush cron
drush cr
```

It was not successfull, so I do this:

```
rm -rf vendor/*
composer update
```

and run again previous commands which It worked.

I though that I could be a problem with PHP version so I update from PHP 7.0 to PHP 7.3, but the error still remains.
I also thought that it could be related with a feeds module installation so delete all feeds content, feeds types, etc .. and unistall and reinstall the module several times (also run drush devel-entity-updates because drupal status report warned of a feeds field that needed to be deleted)although two tables "feeds_feed" and "feeds_subscriptions" still remains in database.

After see that the problem was related with multiples plugins I start looking for a more generic issue (config?, permissions?, ...) but I dont find cause/solution.

**EDIT 1**

Looking for a stack trace I try using drupal console:

```
drupal site:mode dev -v
```

and get this:

```
In DiscoveryTrait.php line 53:

  [Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException]                                                                                                                                               
  The "system.performance" plugin does not exist. Valid plugin IDs for Drupal\Core\TypedData\TypedDataManager are: filter_format, any, float, string, boolean, timespan, language_reference, language, map  
  , binary, timestamp, list, datetime_iso8601, uri, integer, duration_iso8601, email, field_item:comment, field_item:datetime, field_item:daterange, field_item:file_uri, field_item:file, field_item:font  
  awesome_icon, field_item:image, field_item:link, field_item:list_integer, field_item:list_float, field_item:list_string, field_item:path, field_item:telephone, field_item:text, field_item:text_long, f  
  ield_item:text_with_summary, field_item:time_range, field_item:time, field_item:webform, field_item:email, field_item:uri, field_item:entity_reference, field_item:uuid, field_item:timestamp, field_ite  
  m:string_long, field_item:language, field_item:password, field_item:changed, field_item:float, field_item:decimal, field_item:map, field_item:boolean, field_item:integer, field_item:created, field_ite  
  m:string, entity, entity:block, entity:block_content_type, entity:block_content, entity:block_content:basic, entity:captcha_point, entity:comment, entity:comment:comment_forum, entity:comment_type, en  
  tity:contact_form, entity:contact_message, entity:contact_message:feedback, entity:contact_message:personal, entity:editor, entity:field_config, entity:field_storage_config, entity:file, entity:filter  
  _format, entity:image_style, entity:imce_profile, entity:language_content_settings, entity:configurable_language, entity:media_type, entity:media, entity:media:audio, entity:media:file, entity:media:i  
  mage, entity:media:remote_video, entity:media:video, entity:node_type, entity:node,[...], entity:node:page, entity:node:position, entity:rdf_mapping, entity:responsive_image_style, entity:rest_resource_config, entity:rules_reaction_rule, entity:rules_component, entity:s  
  earch_page, entity:shortcut_set, entity:shortcut, entity:shortcut:default, entity:action, entity:menu, entity:taxonomy_vocabulary, entity:taxonomy_term, entity:taxonomy_term:badge_type, entity:taxonom  
  y_term:categories, entity:taxonomy_term:forums, entity:taxonomy_term:materials, entity:taxonomy_term:nivel, entity:taxonomy_term:tags, entity:toolbar_menu_element, entity:tour, entity:user, entity:use  
  r_role, entity:webform_options, entity:webform, entity:webform_submission, [..], entity:menu_link_content, entity:pathauto_pattern, entity  
  :view, entity:base_field_override, entity:entity_view_mode, entity:entity_view_display, entity:entity_form_mode, entity:entity_form_display, entity:date_format, entity_reference                         


Exception trace:
 () at /home/"<user>"/www/"<site>"/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php:53
 Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->doGetDefinition() at /home/"<user>"/www/"<site>"/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryCachedTrait.php:25
 Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinition() at /home/"<user>"/www/"<site>"/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/TypedData/DataDefinition.php:195
 Drupal\Core\TypedData\DataDefinition->getClass() at /home/"<user>"/www/"<site>"/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/TypedData/TypedDataManager.php:86
 Drupal\Core\TypedData\TypedDataManager->createInstance() at /home/"<user>"/www/"<site>"/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/TypedData/TypedDataManager.php:103
 Drupal\Core\TypedData\TypedDataManager->create() at /home/"<user>"/www/"<site>"/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/TypedConfigManager.php:394
 Drupal\Core\Config\TypedConfigManager->createFromNameAndData() at /home/"<user>"/www/"<site>"/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/StorableConfigBase.php:134
 Drupal\Core\Config\StorableConfigBase->getSchemaWrapper() at /home/"<user>"/www/"<site>"/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/StorableConfigBase.php:179
 Drupal\Core\Config\StorableConfigBase->castValue() at /home/"<user>"/www/"<site>"/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/Config.php:212
 Drupal\Core\Config\Config->save() at /home/"<user>"/www/"<site>"/vendor/drupal/console/src/Command/Site/ModeCommand.php:150
 Drupal\Console\Command\Site\ModeCommand->overrideConfigurations() at /home/"<user>"/www/"<site>"/vendor/drupal/console/src/Command/Site/ModeCommand.php:87
 Drupal\Console\Command\Site\ModeCommand->execute() at /home/"<user>"/www/"<site>"/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:255
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /home/"<user>"/www/"<site>"/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:987
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /home/"<user>"/www/"<site>"/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:255
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /home/"<user>"/www/"<site>"/vendor/drupal/console-core/src/Application.php:184
 Drupal\Console\Core\Application->doRun() at /home/"<user>"/www/"<site>"/vendor/drupal/console/src/Application.php:64
 Drupal\Console\Application->doRun() at /home/"<user>"/www/"<site>"/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:148
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /home/"<user>"/www/"<site>"/vendor/drupal/console/bin/drupal.php:89
 require() at /home/"<user>"/www/"<site>"/vendor/drupal/console/bin/drupal:4
```

**EDIT 2**

looking at the database I found two tables from feeds module (supposed to be uninstalled)

feeds_feed
feeds_subscription

running drupal console commnand `drupal debug:module` feeds appears as the only module uninstalled with a schema version defined

```
ID     Name   Package  version      schema version  status      origin
...
feeds  Feeds  Feeds  8.x-3.0-alpha5    8001         Uninstalled no core
...
```

**EDIT 3**

After enable debugging ([How do I enable developer/debug mode?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/127182/how-do-i-enable-developer-debug-mode))

I got new clues about the error ( trying to create a view) but my lack of drupal core knowledge stops me from understanding where final cause is:

```
</br></br><em class="placeholder">Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException</em>: The &quot;views.view.*&quot; plugin does not exist. Valid plugin IDs for Drupal\Core\TypedData\TypedDataManager are: filter_format, any, float, string, boolean, timespan, language_reference, language, map, binary, timestamp, list, datetime_iso8601, uri, integer, duration_iso8601, email, field_item:comment, field_item:datetime, field_item:daterange, field_item:file_uri, field_item:file, field_item:fontawesome_icon, field_item:image, field_item:link, field_item:list_integer, field_item:list_float, field_item:list_string, field_item:path, field_item:telephone, field_item:text, field_item:text_long, field_item:text_with_summary, field_item:time_range, field_item:time, field_item:webform, field_item:email, field_item:uri, field_item:entity_reference, field_item:uuid, field_item:timestamp, field_item:string_long, field_item:language, field_item:password, field_item:changed, field_item:float, field_item:decimal, field_item:map, field_item:boolean, field_item:integer, field_item:created, field_item:string, entity, entity:block, entity:block_content_type, entity:block_content, entity:block_content:basic, entity:captcha_point,
[...]
entity:entity_view_mode, entity:entity_view_display, entity:entity_form_mode, entity:entity_form_display, entity:date_format, entity_reference in <em class="placeholder">Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager-&gt;doGetDefinition()</em> (line <em class="placeholder">53</em> of <em class="placeholder">core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php</em>). <pre class="backtrace">Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager-&gt;getDefinition(&#039;views.view.*&#039;) (Line: 195)
Drupal\Core\TypedData\DataDefinition-&gt;getClass() (Line: 86)
Drupal\Core\TypedData\TypedDataManager-&gt;createInstance(&#039;views.view.*&#039;, Array) (Line: 103)
Drupal\Core\TypedData\TypedDataManager-&gt;create(Object, Array) (Line: 394)
Drupal\Core\Config\TypedConfigManager-&gt;createFromNameAndData(&#039;views.view.test2&#039;, Array) (Line: 134)
Drupal\Core\Config\StorableConfigBase-&gt;getSchemaWrapper() (Line: 179)
Drupal\Core\Config\StorableConfigBase-&gt;castValue(&#039;uuid&#039;, &#039;c2f6326b-a77f-4f1e-9698-cb96154252cb&#039;) (Line: 212)
Drupal\Core\Config\Config-&gt;save() (Line: 284)
Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\ConfigEntityStorage-&gt;doSave(&#039;test2&#039;, Object) (Line: 449)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase-&gt;save(Object) (Line: 263)
Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\ConfigEntityStorage-&gt;save(Object) (Line: 394)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityBase-&gt;save() (Line: 613)
Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\ConfigEntityBase-&gt;save() (Line: 993)
Drupal\views_ui\ViewUI-&gt;save() (Line: 191)
Drupal\views_ui\ViewAddForm-&gt;submitForm(Array, Object)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 111)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormSubmitter-&gt;executeSubmitHandlers(Array, Object) (Line: 51)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormSubmitter-&gt;doSubmitForm(Array, Object) (Line: 590)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder-&gt;processForm(&#039;view_add_form&#039;, Array, Object) (Line: 319)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder-&gt;buildForm(Object, Object) (Line: 93)
Drupal\Core\Controller\FormController-&gt;getContentResult(Object, Object)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 123)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber-&gt;Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 582)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer-&gt;executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 124)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber-&gt;wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array) (Line: 97)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber-&gt;Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 151)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel-&gt;handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 68)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel-&gt;handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session-&gt;handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle-&gt;handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 106)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache-&gt;pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 85)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache-&gt;handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware-&gt;handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 52)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware-&gt;handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel-&gt;handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 693)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel-&gt;handle(Object) (Line: 19)
</pre>
```

Comment: So to clarify, `whatever` means one of `views.view.`, `core.extension`, `node.type.`, `system.menu.*`? Are all of those having the same stack trace? That doesn't make sense because none of the listed items there are typed data data types. Unrelated to that question, this usually happens when missing a module dependency, but it's unclear what is going on from what you provided.

Comment: Yes, whatever means one of views.view., core.extension, node.type., system.menu.*?

All errors have same list of Valid IDs and finisth with pointing to line 53 in DiscoveryTrait.php (edit answer to add a stacktrace)

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for updating. I run postgresql and haven't run into anything related so I think that's probably not the issue here either. I couldn't install drupal-console on my 8.7.x because of conflicts with symfony/filesystem, but I tried a config:set of system.performance in drush to see if I could replicate on postgresql, but could not.

Comment: There are clues about a failed feeds module uninstallation (EDIT 2 in question).

Comment: what happens when you run `composer dumpautoload` in project root?

Comment: after run composer dumpautoload i got this:
"Generated autoload files containing 558 classes" 
but error still persits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of issue was an indentation error on a config file in a subtheme (../config/schema/subtheme.schema.yml).

This file (from a my custom Bootstrap Barrio subtheme) have no indentation after "mapping:" :

```
#Schema for the configuration files of the Bootstrap Barrio Subtheme.

totaltheme.settings:
  type: theme_settings
  label: 'Totaltheme settings'

mapping:
  bootstrap_barrio_sidebar_position:
    type: text
    label: 'Sidebar Position'
  bootstrap_barrio_content_offset:
  ...
```

instead of this

```
#Schema for the configuration files of the Bootstrap Barrio Subtheme.

totaltheme.settings:
  type: theme_settings
  label: 'Totaltheme settings'
  mapping:
    bootstrap_barrio_sidebar_position:
      type: text
      label: 'Sidebar Position'
    bootstrap_barrio_content_offset:
    ...
```

This thing caused all "Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "{whatever}" plugin does not exist." errors.

I found a copy of the file with .save at end of filename (subtheme.schema.yml.save) with the correct indentation so I supposed something happened while editing the file (using nano in linux).

Answer (score 1):

Try this command, it works well.

```
drush eval "drupal_flush_all_caches();"
```

or

```
drush cr discovery
```

Refer: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3056633

Answer (score 1):

possibly an APC server cache problem ?

Add this to local.settings.php

```
$settings['class_loader_auto_detect'] = FALSE;
```

or restart server

Comment: OMG thank you! Not an error related to @OP but I was running into WSOD because I had installed a module in both custom and contrib. I was trying to remove the one in contrib folder but it kept breaking. Restarting apache was all that was needed - it was indeed an APC cache issue