# While clearing cache i am getting 'Page isnt working'

Tags: forms

Whenever i use classname extends FormBase the clear cache crashes and whenever i remove it it works again.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\API_crud\Form;


use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class ApiCrud extends FormBase {
    public function getFormId() {
        return 'api_form';
    }

    public function buidForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        $form['title'] = [
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => $this->t('API: '),
            '#required' => TRUE,
        ];
        $form['actions'] = [
            '#type' => 'actions',
        ];
        $form['actions']['submit'] = [
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
        ];
        return $form;
    }

}
```

```
apiAuth.form:
  path: '/apiAuth'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\API_crud\Form\ApiCrud'
    # _controller: '\Drupal\API_crud\Controller\apiCrudController::Welcome'
    _title: 'API_Authentication'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

[image]

Comment: See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/127182/how-do-i-enable-developer-debug-mode/223964#223964

Comment: It's worth investing time (and/or money) in learning to use a good IDE. VS code is a nice free one, PHPStorm is a nice paid one, for example. If you were using such an IDE it would have altered you to the fact your form class is missing methods from `FormInterface`, and you would've fixed it quickly.

Answer (score 2):

As Clive is hinting in his comment some methods are missing in your class.
You need to add at least the methods "buildForm" and "submitForm" to you class. (you also have a typo in buidForm)

This should work:

```php
<?php

namespace Drupal\API_crud\Form;


use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class ApiCrud extends FormBase {
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'api_form';
  }

  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['title'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('API: '),
      '#required' => TRUE,
    ];
    $form['actions'] = [
      '#type' => 'actions',
    ];
    $form['actions']['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
    ];
    return $form;
  }

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // TODO: Implement submitForm() method.
  }

}
```